# Hive collect_list() does not collect NULL values

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-udf

I am trying to collect a column with `NULL`s along with some values in that column...But `collect_list` ignores the `NULL`s and collects only the ones with values in it. Is there a way to retrieve the `NULL`s along with other values ?

```
SELECT col1, col2, collect_list(col3) as col3
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY col1, col2, col3)
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

Actual col3 values

```
0.9
NULL
NULL
0.7
0.6
```

Resulting col3 values

```
[0.9, 0.7, 0.6]
```

I was hoping that there is a hive solution that looks like this `[0.9, NULL, NULL, 0.7, 0.6]` after applying the collect_list.

Answer (score 8):

This function works like this, but I've found the following workaround.
Add a **case when** statement to your query to check and keep NULLs.

```
SELECT col1, 
    col2, 
    collect_list(CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE col3 END) as col3
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY col1, col2, col3)
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Now, because you had a string element ('NULL') the whole result set is an array of strings.
At the end just convert the array of strings to an array of double values.

Comment: I used a different method that does the same thing. Its still probably an array of strings which is an issue. What happens when I convert the null's to doubles ?
`SELECT col1, 
    col2, 
    collect_list(coalesce(col3, "NULL") as col3
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY col1, col2, col3)
GROUP BY col1, col2`

Comment: If you convert null's to doubles the result is None (with this statement: cast(null as double)). However the collect_list is ignoring both NULL and None values.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If your column is STRING it won't be having a NULL value even though your external file does not have any data for that column

> you can a where condition with validation check like "col3 is NULL and
>   col3 is not NULL"